# Textbox in Datatemplate MVVM

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm

I am having problems binding a textbox to my viewmodel.

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="ContentDetail" >
   <StackPanel  Orientation="Horizontal" Height="500"">             
      <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding SelectedCall.CUCODE }" />
   </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

I know the binding is fine as I have it also bound outside the datatemplate

```
DataContext="{Binding HelpdeskViewModel, Source={StaticResource ServiceLocator}}"

dx:ThemeManager.ThemeName="VS2010" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedCall,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}">
```

Any pointers would be gratefully accepted.

Edit:

```
<dxg:GridControl.DetailDescriptor>
  <dxg:TabViewDetailDescriptor>
      <dxg:TabViewDetailDescriptor.DetailDescriptors>
         <dxg:ContentDetailDescriptor ContentTemplate="{StaticResource ContentDetail}" HeaderContent="More Detail" >
         </dxg:ContentDetailDescriptor>
      </dxg:TabViewDetailDescriptor.DetailDescriptors>
    </dxg:TabViewDetailDescriptor>
   </dxg:GridControl.DetailDescriptor>
```

Comment: nothing is appearing in the textbox. i am using devExpress so not sure if that is causing problems

Comment: it cannot do the problem

Comment: Take a debug point into your codebehind, and check the DataContext. It will be null as I think.

Comment: ihave <TextBlock TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="{Binding SelectedCall.CUCODE}"/> outside the template and it populates fine

Comment: I have added the devexpress xaml. It must be the problem if you are not seeing anything. I will read more this eve. Thanks

Comment: Is `HelpdeskViewModel` the DataContext for your GridControl.DetailDescriptor? If so, does `HelpdeskViewModel` have a **public** `SelectedCall` property? If so, does SelectedCall have a **public** `CUCODE` property? (note: public properties are required for any xaml that is NOT wpf)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Items within a Template are bound to the current item in the Template (so your datacontext in this scope isn't your window's viewmodel, but the current item).

I assume SelectedCall is a property on your window's viewmodel and not a property on each bound item, so you can't access that. If it's also a property of each model then simply bind to CUCODE, else if it's  a single per window item, you'd have to trace back to the ancestor window & bind to the datacontext of the window instead of the one automatically set for you within the context of the Template.

You're probably looking for something like that

```
<TextBlock Text="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=SelectedCall.CUCODE }}" />
```